# Template Deduction Problem when adding equivalence check in std::enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, simd, avx2

I am trying to benchmark different ways to sum. I'd like using an interface as follows

```cpp
avx2_sum<sum_algorithm::normal>(container.begin(), container.end());
```

However, my attempt

```cpp
enum class sum_algorithm: char{
    normal,
    kahan,
    twofold_fast //https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0248.pdf
};


template<sum_algorithm algorithm_t, typename iterator_t, typename sum_t = typename std::iterator_traits<iterator_t>::value_type,
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<sum_t, double>::value && (algorithm_t == sum_algorithm::normal)> = true>
sum_t avx2_sum(const iterator_t begin, const iterator_t end) noexcept {
    // SIMD-parallel summation stage
    auto running_sums = _mm256_set1_pd(0);
    auto iterator_skip = 256/sizeof(sum_t);
    for (iterator_t it = begin; it + iterator_skip < end; it += iterator_skip){
        //TODO: flip to double load reduction
        running_sums = _mm256_add_pd(_mm256_load_pd(it), running_sums);
    }

    // Serial summation
    running_sums = _mm256_hadd_pd(running_sums, running_sums);
    running_sums = _mm256_hadd_pd(running_sums, running_sums);
    return _mm256_cvtsd_f64(running_sums);
}
```

produces the following:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'avx2_sum'
    std::cout << "avx2<float, normal>: " << accumulators::avx2_sum<algo::normal>(float_arr.begin(), float_arr.end()) <<"\n";
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rlfactory/dev/thommmj1/cppbenchmarks/cpp_utils/algorithms/cpu_accumulators.hpp:55:11: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_same<float, double>::value' was not satisfied [with algorithm_t = accumulators::sum_algorithm::normal, iterator_t = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float *, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, sum_t = float]
    sum_t avx2_sum(const iterator_t begin, const iterator_t end) noexcept {
          ^
/home/rlfactory/dev/thommmj1/cppbenchmarks/cpp_utils/algorithms/cpu_accumulators.hpp:71:11: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with algorithm_t = accumulators::sum_algorithm::normal, iterator_t = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float *, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, sum_t = float]: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<float, float>::value && ((sum_algorithm)'\x00' == sum_algorithm::normal)>' (aka 'void')
    sum_t avx2_sum(const iterator_t begin, const iterator_t end) noexcept {
          ^
/home/rlfactory/dev/thommmj1/cppbenchmarks/cpp_utils/algorithms/cpu_accumulators.hpp:87:11: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_same<float, double>::value' was not satisfied [with algorithm_t = accumulators::sum_algorithm::normal, iterator_t = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float *, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, sum_t = float]
    sum_t avx2_sum(const iterator_t begin, const iterator_t end) noexcept {
          ^
/home/rlfactory/dev/thommmj1/cppbenchmarks/cpp_utils/algorithms/cpu_accumulators.hpp:109:11: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_same<float, float>::value && ((accumulators::sum_algorithm)'\x00' == sum_algorithm::kahan)' was not satisfied [with algorithm_t = accumulators::sum_algorithm::normal, iterator_t = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float *, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >, sum_t = float]
    sum_t avx2_sum(const iterator_t begin, const iterator_t end) noexcept {
```

I don't understand how deduction doesn't work here. Without the algorithm_t template portion and check, it works just fine. Perhaps it's due to my using statement? `using algo = accumulators::sum_algorithm;`

Comment: According to the error message you are trying to pass `sum_algorithm::normal` and a `float` iterator. Your shown template requires `sum_algorithm::normal` and a value type of `double`. There is apparently also an overload accepting `sum_algorithm::kahan` with a value type of `float`. Neither match. The second candidate in the error message seems to have some other problem going on, but you are not showing that overload, so I can't comment on it.

Comment: Since you tagged `c++20`: You don't need SFINAE and `std::enable_if` anymore since C++20. It has been made much simpler and cleaner. Just write `requires /* condition here */` under the template head or the function head instead.

Comment: Your error `a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'std::enable_if_t<...>' (aka 'void')`: You forgot the second argument `std::enable_if_t<..., bool> = true` (a typo if this is what fixes it)

Comment: @user17732522 requires fixed it.